# Where should small utility programs store their preferences?

Tags: file-management

I have several utility programs that do not have their own directory and are just a single executable. Typically I put the binary in /usr/local/bin. A problem I have is how to manage preference settings.

One idea is to use environment variables and require the user to define such variables, for example, in their bash.rc. I am a little reluctant, however, to clutter up the bash.rc with miscellaneous preference settings for a minor program.

Is there a Standard (or standard recommendation), that defines some place or method that is appropriate for storing preferences for small utility programs that do not have their own directory?

Comment: When you add user preferences, this makes this tool pretty much unusable for scripting, because transferring a script from one system to another can then change its behaviour.

Comment: @SimonRichter It's not a script, its a C binary.

Comment: The question is whether a script may want to call your binary and expect that it always behaves the exact same way when called with the same parameters. There is absolutely room for local configuration here, e.g. `gpg` has a configuration file with the user's identity, so scripts don't have to list it, but you wouldn't want a config file to switch the output format, because a script using `gpg` to verify a signature would not expect that.

Comment: @SimonRichter There can be a flag to select a config file, including no config file at all. For example vim can be run with `vim -u NONE`. This way it behaves the same on all systems. Or the tool can have a special scripting interface because e.g. parsing its normal output is not recommended. Alternatively the tool can check if it's being run interactively and omit config when it's not, but this might be confusing in some cases.

Comment: @SimonRichter An example of a CLI tool (often used for scripting) with a config file is `wget`: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Startup-File.html#Startup-File

Comment: @SamEstep, most of the options typically configured there are things needed for the command to work in the local environment, not changes in behaviour -- but I would absolutely expect scripts to break when my wgetrc specified to send an Accept-Type header, for example.

Comment: @SimonRichter "git" is one of those tools where the configuration can change behavior.  Still very useful though.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Small utilities for interactive desktop use would be expected to follow the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and keep their config files under

```
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME
```

or (if that is empty or unset) default to

```
$HOME/.config
```

The picture is a little less clear for non-GUI tools, since they might run on systems which are headless or which don't otherwise adhere to XDG/freedesktop standards.

However, there's no obvious drawback to using `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` if set or `$HOME/.config` if not, and it should be relatively unsurprising everywhere.

Comment: confirmed here as well https://golang.org/pkg/os#UserConfigDir

Comment: The key phrase is *for interactive desktop use*.  Command line executables should probably not have definable preferences at all and should prefer command line arguments for customization of behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that. Lots of command-line executables have persistent per-user config - for example `git` has user-level config, and I wouldn't really object if my `~/.gitrc` lived in `~/.config/git` instead.

Comment: I'd still say that git falls under "interactive desktop use" though and you can ask it to not use any config file if you want to use it within a script. But tools like `cp`, `ls`, `dirname` etc. shouldn't have a config file, which was what @J... meant.

Comment: Sure, but then htop does have a config file. Perhaps the correct distinction is _mostly used interactively_ vs. _mostly used in scripts_ or something, but "CLI programs" is definitely too broad.

Comment: Yes, I think more precisely the idea being that CLI executables should always produce deterministic results.  If the config options don't change that, then OK.

Comment: No, we're back to the fact that `git` is an _interactive_ CLI executable, and I absolutely want it to produce commits that depend on the per-user config. You mean "non-interactive" CLI executables, or CLI executables when used non-interactively. It's a fuzzy distinction.

Answer (score 19):

Although historically, a lot of programs used $HOME/.$PROGNAME the result is that home directories are becoming a bit messy. The preferred convention seems to be $HOME/.config/$PROGNAME nowadays (I currently have 173 dotfiles in ~, most of which are historical artefacts, and 80 in ~/.config).

Note that there is an important difference between **config** and **preferences**. The former is the system wide policy and should only be editable by root, while the latter should controlled by users. Preeferences should NOT be stored anywhere outside of $HOME.

Comment: Yes, I notice that trend, but the problem is that they are creating a bunch of directories to store just one file. For example, I have ~/.config/sway/config where config is just a single file and it is the only thing in that directory.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you putting a single file in .config rather than a directory - but a single inode is not a huge cost.

Comment: They don't _need_ to do that (but perhaps they want to allow multiple config files in future). Just `~/.config/swaycfg` or whatever should be fine too.

Comment: I see, so I would have something like ~/.config/my-util.config for example?

Comment: Yep, that should be fine.

Comment: Two small, related advantages to creating a subdirectory instead of just a file: 1) if you ever in the future need another file, you've already got a directory to keep them together, and won't need to handle migrating from single file -> subdir; 2) similarly, if a user wants to keep two versions of the config file for some reason, both can be kept together in the subdir (also pairs nicely with allowing them to pass the config file to use on the command line)

Comment: Please note that `~/.config` is the default path, but the actual user-set path is stored in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. Make sure to use the user's preferred path when it's set and not empty.

Comment: @symcbean while "huge cost" is of course subjective and you are correct, a directory is more than an inode, and more importantly, filesystems often try to keep files in a directory together, so creating a subdirectory will likely destroy locality. If all single-file configs are together in one directory, they are likely near to each other on disk, which can have a human-noticable difference in speed.

Answer (score 9):

**Opinion**

You put the utilities into `/usr/local/bin` so you could reasonably use `/usr/local/etc/{program_name}` for system-wide settings, or `$HOME/.{program_name}` for local per-user configuration

In a shell script, since `$0` contains the program name, these pathnames could be determined as `"/usr/local/etc/${0##*/}"` and `"$HOME/.${0##*/}"`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So, if I have a progam like /usr/local/bin/my-util, then I can have the file /usr/local/etc/my-util.config to store preferences?

Comment: You can have anything you like. That's why this is only an opinion.

Comment: Well, I don't want to do something weird and idiosyncratic. I want to do something that people will expect and understand and recognize as standard practice.

Comment: `/usr/local/etc` is for host-specific config, not user-specific config. [FHS ref](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html)

Comment: @Useless, that's what I was intending. I've clarified that explicitly now

Comment: @Tyler, this is what I would do, and I would expect it configured like this.

Answer (score 2):

> Where should small utility programs store their preferences?

**This is a matter of opinion !**

Is there a Standard (or standard recommendation),

#### You might read the [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/) then [hier(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html)

And you should study for inspiration the source code and the documentation of *several* open source software. BTW the conventions for [zsh](https://zsh.org/) are different of those for [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and your login shell (often described in `/etc/passwd`, see [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html)) could be changed with [chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html); I prefer to use `zsh`

---

### A source of inspiration might be existing GNU programs, including [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)

When you compile one of them from its source code, you run a `./configure` script (generated by [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)) and that script usually accepts some `--help`  command.

As an example, for GNU emacs, `./configure --help`  gives

```
 `configure' configures GNU Emacs 28.0.50 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

 Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

 To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
 VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

 Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

 Configuration:
   -h, --help              display this help and exit
       --help=short        display options specific to this package
       --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
   -V, --version           display version information and exit
   -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
       --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
   -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
   -n, --no-create         do not create output files
       --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

 Installation directories:
   --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                           [/usr/local]
   --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                           [PREFIX]

 By default, `make install' will install all the files in
 `/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
 an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
 for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

 For better control, use the options below.

 Fine tuning of the installation directories:
   --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
   --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
   --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
   --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
   --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
   --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
   --runstatedir=DIR       modifiable per-process data [LOCALSTATEDIR/run]
   --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
   --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
   --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
   --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
   --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
   --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
   --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
   --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
   --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/emacs]
   --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
   --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
   --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
   --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

 Program names:
   --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
   --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
   --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names

 X features:
   --x-includes=DIR    X include files are in DIR
   --x-libraries=DIR   X library files are in DIR

 System types:
   --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
   --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]

 Optional Features:
   --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
   --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
   --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
   --disable-ns-self-contained
                           disable self contained build under NeXTstep
   --enable-locallisppath=PATH
                           directories Emacs should search for lisp files
                           specific to this site
   --enable-checking[=LIST]
                           enable expensive checks. With LIST, enable only
                           specific categories of checks. Categories are:
                           all,yes,no. Flags are: stringbytes, stringoverrun,
                           stringfreelist, structs, glyphs
   --enable-profiling      build emacs with low-level, gprof profiling support.
                           Mainly useful for debugging Emacs itself. May not
                           work on all platforms. Stops profiler.el working.
   --enable-autodepend     automatically generate dependencies to .h-files.
                           Requires gcc, enabled if found.
   --enable-gtk-deprecation-warnings
                           Show Gtk+/Gdk deprecation warnings for Gtk+ >= 3.0
   --disable-build-details Make the build more deterministic by omitting host
                           names, time stamps, etc. from the output.
   --disable-largefile     omit support for large files
   --enable-gcc-warnings[=TYPE]
                           control generation of GCC warnings. The TYPE 'yes'
                           means to fail if any warnings are issued;
                           'warn-only' means issue warnings without failing
                           (default for developer builds); 'no' means disable
                           warnings (default for non-developer builds).
   --enable-check-lisp-object-type
                           Enable compile time checks for the Lisp_Object data
                           type, which can catch some bugs during development.
   --enable-link-time-optimization
                           build with link-time optimization (experimental; see
                           INSTALL)
   --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")
   --enable-cross-guesses={conservative|risky}
                           specify policy for cross-compilation guesses
   --disable-acl           do not support ACLs

 Optional Packages:
   --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
   --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
   --without-all           omit almost all features and build small executable
                           with minimal dependencies
   --with-mailutils        rely on GNU Mailutils, so that the --without-pop
                           through --with-mailhost options are irrelevant; this
                           is the default if GNU Mailutils is installed
   --with-pop              Support POP mail retrieval if Emacs movemail is used
                           (not recommended, as Emacs movemail POP is
                           insecure). This is the default only on native
                           MS-Windows.
   --with-kerberos         support Kerberos-authenticated POP
   --with-kerberos5        support Kerberos version 5 authenticated POP
   --with-hesiod           support Hesiod to get the POP server host
   --with-mail-unlink      unlink, rather than empty, mail spool after reading
   --with-mailhost=HOSTNAME
                           string giving default POP mail host
   --with-sound=VALUE      compile with sound support (VALUE one of: yes, alsa,
                           oss, bsd-ossaudio, no; default yes). Only for
                           GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, MinGW, Cygwin.
   --with-pdumper=VALUE    enable pdumper support unconditionally ('yes', 'no',
                           or 'auto': default 'auto')
   --with-unexec=VALUE     enable unexec support unconditionally ('yes', 'no',
                           or 'auto': default 'auto')
   --with-dumping=VALUE    kind of dumping to use for initial Emacs build
                           (VALUE one of: pdumper, unexec, none; default
                           pdumper)
   --with-x-toolkit=KIT    use an X toolkit (KIT one of: yes or gtk, gtk2,
                           gtk3, lucid or athena, motif, no)
   --with-wide-int         prefer wide Emacs integers (typically 62-bit); on
                           32-bit hosts, this allows buffer and string size up
                           to 2GB, at the cost of 10% to 30% slowdown of Lisp
                           interpreter and larger memory footprint
   --without-xpm           don't compile with XPM image support
   --without-jpeg          don't compile with JPEG image support
   --without-tiff          don't compile with TIFF image support
   --without-gif           don't compile with GIF image support
   --without-png           don't compile with PNG image support
   --without-rsvg          don't compile with SVG image support
   --without-lcms2         don't compile with Little CMS support
   --without-libsystemd    don't compile with libsystemd support
   --without-cairo         don't compile with Cairo drawing
   --without-xml2          don't compile with XML parsing support
   --with-imagemagick      compile with ImageMagick image support
   --without-native-image-api
                           don't use native image APIs (GDI+ on Windows)
   --with-json             compile with native JSON support
   --without-xft           don't use XFT for anti aliased fonts
   --without-harfbuzz      don't use HarfBuzz for text shaping
   --without-libotf        don't use libotf for OpenType font support
   --without-m17n-flt      don't use m17n-flt for text shaping
   --without-toolkit-scroll-bars
                           don't use Motif/Xaw3d/GTK toolkit scroll bars
   --without-xaw3d         don't use Xaw3d
   --without-xim           at runtime, default X11 XIM to off
   --without-xdbe          don't use X11 double buffering support
   --with-ns               use Nextstep (macOS Cocoa or GNUstep) windowing
                           system. On by default on macOS.
   --with-w32              use native MS Windows GUI in a Cygwin build
   --without-gpm           don't use -lgpm for mouse support on a GNU/Linux
                           console
   --without-dbus          don't compile with D-Bus support
   --with-gconf            compile with Gconf support (Gsettings replaces this)
   --without-gsettings     don't compile with GSettings support
   --without-selinux       don't compile with SELinux support
   --without-gnutls        don't use -lgnutls for SSL/TLS support
   --without-zlib          don't compile with zlib decompression support
   --without-modules       don't compile with dynamic modules support
   --without-threads       don't compile with elisp threading support
   --with-file-notification=LIB
                           use a file notification library (LIB one of: yes,
                           inotify, kqueue, gfile, w32, no)
   --with-xwidgets         enable use of xwidgets in Emacs buffers (requires
                           gtk3 or macOS Cocoa)
   --without-makeinfo      don't require makeinfo for building manuals
   --without-compress-install
                           don't compress some files (.el, .info, etc.) when
                           installing. Equivalent to: make GZIP_PROG= install
   --with-gameuser=USER_OR_GROUP
                           user for shared game score files. An argument
                           prefixed by ':' specifies a group instead.
   --with-gnustep-conf=FILENAME
                           name of GNUstep configuration file to use on systems
                           where the command 'gnustep-config' does not work;
                           default $GNUSTEP_CONFIG_FILE, or
                           /etc/GNUstep/GNUstep.conf
   --with-x                use the X Window System
   --without-libgmp        do not use the GNU Multiple Precision (GMP) library;
                           this is the default on systems lacking libgmp.
   --without-included-regex
                           don't compile regex; this is the default on systems
                           with recent-enough versions of the GNU C Library
                           (use with caution on other systems).

 Some influential environment variables:
   CC          C compiler command
   CFLAGS      C compiler flags
   LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
               nonstandard directory <lib dir>
   LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
   CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
               you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
   CPP         C preprocessor
   PKG_CONFIG  path to pkg-config utility
   PKG_CONFIG_PATH
               directories to add to pkg-config's search path
   PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
               path overriding pkg-config's built-in search path
   ALSA_CFLAGS C compiler flags for ALSA, overriding pkg-config
   ALSA_LIBS   linker flags for ALSA, overriding pkg-config
   XMKMF       Path to xmkmf, Makefile generator for X Window System
   OBJC        Objective C compiler command
   OBJCFLAGS   Objective C compiler flags
   RSVG_CFLAGS C compiler flags for RSVG, overriding pkg-config
   RSVG_LIBS   linker flags for RSVG, overriding pkg-config
   IMAGEMAGICK_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for IMAGEMAGICK, overriding pkg-config
   IMAGEMAGICK_LIBS
               linker flags for IMAGEMAGICK, overriding pkg-config
   GTK_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for GTK, overriding pkg-config
   GTK_LIBS    linker flags for GTK, overriding pkg-config
   WEBKIT_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for WEBKIT, overriding pkg-config
   WEBKIT_LIBS linker flags for WEBKIT, overriding pkg-config
   DBUS_CFLAGS C compiler flags for DBUS, overriding pkg-config
   DBUS_LIBS   linker flags for DBUS, overriding pkg-config
   GSETTINGS_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for GSETTINGS, overriding pkg-config
   GSETTINGS_LIBS
               linker flags for GSETTINGS, overriding pkg-config
   GCONF_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for GCONF, overriding pkg-config
   GCONF_LIBS  linker flags for GCONF, overriding pkg-config
   GOBJECT_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for GOBJECT, overriding pkg-config
   GOBJECT_LIBS
               linker flags for GOBJECT, overriding pkg-config
   LIBGNUTLS_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for LIBGNUTLS, overriding pkg-config
   LIBGNUTLS_LIBS
               linker flags for LIBGNUTLS, overriding pkg-config
   LIBSYSTEMD_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for LIBSYSTEMD, overriding pkg-config
   LIBSYSTEMD_LIBS
               linker flags for LIBSYSTEMD, overriding pkg-config
   JSON_CFLAGS C compiler flags for JSON, overriding pkg-config
   JSON_LIBS   linker flags for JSON, overriding pkg-config
   KQUEUE_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for KQUEUE, overriding pkg-config
   KQUEUE_LIBS linker flags for KQUEUE, overriding pkg-config
   GFILENOTIFY_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for GFILENOTIFY, overriding pkg-config
   GFILENOTIFY_LIBS
               linker flags for GFILENOTIFY, overriding pkg-config
   CAIRO_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for CAIRO, overriding pkg-config
   CAIRO_LIBS  linker flags for CAIRO, overriding pkg-config
   FREETYPE_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for FREETYPE, overriding pkg-config
   FREETYPE_LIBS
               linker flags for FREETYPE, overriding pkg-config
   FONTCONFIG_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for FONTCONFIG, overriding pkg-config
   FONTCONFIG_LIBS
               linker flags for FONTCONFIG, overriding pkg-config
   XFT_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for XFT, overriding pkg-config
   XFT_LIBS    linker flags for XFT, overriding pkg-config
   LIBOTF_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for LIBOTF, overriding pkg-config
   LIBOTF_LIBS linker flags for LIBOTF, overriding pkg-config
   M17N_FLT_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for M17N_FLT, overriding pkg-config
   M17N_FLT_LIBS
               linker flags for M17N_FLT, overriding pkg-config
   HARFBUZZ_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for HARFBUZZ, overriding pkg-config
   HARFBUZZ_LIBS
               linker flags for HARFBUZZ, overriding pkg-config
   LCMS2_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for LCMS2, overriding pkg-config
   LCMS2_LIBS  linker flags for LCMS2, overriding pkg-config
   PNG_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for PNG, overriding pkg-config
   PNG_LIBS    linker flags for PNG, overriding pkg-config
   XRANDR_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for XRANDR, overriding pkg-config
   XRANDR_LIBS linker flags for XRANDR, overriding pkg-config
   XINERAMA_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for XINERAMA, overriding pkg-config
   XINERAMA_LIBS
               linker flags for XINERAMA, overriding pkg-config
   XFIXES_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for XFIXES, overriding pkg-config
   XFIXES_LIBS linker flags for XFIXES, overriding pkg-config
   LIBXML2_CFLAGS
               C compiler flags for LIBXML2, overriding pkg-config
   LIBXML2_LIBS
               linker flags for LIBXML2, overriding pkg-config

 Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
 it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.

 Report bugs to <bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org>.
 GNU Emacs home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/>.
 General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
```

I often compile the latest GNU emacs snapshot. And I did:

```
'./configure'  'CC=gcc-10' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g' '--program-suffix=-trunk' \
               '--prefix=/usr/local' '--sysconfdir=/etc/local'
```

which is kept in the `config.status` generated file.

BTW, to get the configuration options of your [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) just run `gcc -v`

#### Consider also studying the package management system of your Linux

E.g. [Debian](https://debian.org/) (or your favorite GNU/Linux distribution), and reading [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

Read also [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html).

On other POSIX or Unix-like systems (e.g. Solaris or MacOSX) things are *slightly* different.

You could decide to pass options thru program options. Then see also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) answer.

In several open source programs I am coding, I also document conventions about environment variables (see [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and query them using [getenv(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) ...) and I often decide to have a common prefix for them. So in the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (an open source symbolic artificial intelligence project) we are using of course `REFPERSYS_`, for example coding `getenv("REFPERSYS_HOME")` ... And in [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) (a static analysis / software engineering tool funded by [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) and [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) European projects, see [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report) the prefix is `BISMON_`

For graphical user interface applications, your favorite GUI framework (such as [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/)) defines its own preferences.

#### Consider also embedding some interpreter inside your programs

You could easily embed [Lua](https://lua.oirg/) or [GNU Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) (or [Python](https://python.org/)) inside your programs coded in C or C++. These interpreters have each their own convention and syntax. The advantage of extending some *existing* interpreter is potential familiarity for advanced users of these scripting languages.

#### Consider also extending your programs with plugins.

On Linux, a plugin is loaded by [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and used thru [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) in programs coded in C or C++. If you accept them, please document the public API of your program.

Many major Linux programs (in particular the [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) browser and the GCC compiler, but also [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [zsh](https://zsh.org/)) accept [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)). The advantage is that extensibility becomes easier, and the advanced user don't have to recompile some huge open source program to customize it. Another advantage is speed. However, learning a plugin API is a significant effort.